# Matplotlib doesn't forget previous data when saving figures with savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3],'ro')
plt.axis([-4,4,-4,4])
plt.savefig('azul.png')
plt.plot([0,1,2],[0,0,0],'ro')
plt.axis([-4,4,-4,4])
plt.savefig('amarillo.png')
```

Output:

[image: azul]
[image: amarillo]

Why does this happen and how to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is a completely expected behaviour. You can plot as many data as often as you want to the same figure, which is very often very useful.

If you want to create several figures in the same script using the matplotlib state machine, you need to first close one figure before generating the next.

So in this very simple case, just add `plt.close()` between figure creation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3],'bo')
plt.axis([-4,4,-4,4])
plt.savefig('azul.png')
plt.close()
plt.plot([0,1,2],[0,0,0],'yo')
plt.axis([-4,4,-4,4])
plt.savefig('amarillo.png')
```

Comment: I think the more common method used is to do `plt.figure()`, which creates a new figure and keeps the first figure alive (in fact, `plt.plot` implicitly calls `plt.figure` when no figure is active). Of course in this case, both methods result in effectively the same outcome.

Comment: Thank you so much. as a new member to ML, you saved my time.